# Error installing socket.io on Windows

Tags: socket.io, npm

I get this error message when I run "npm install socket.io." Can anyone help with this? Is the main problem with the "ws@0.5.0 script," whatever that is?

Also, what does the "node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log" mean? I've head that Python may be related to this problem, but I don't really know how.

Thanks a lot for your help!

```
$ npm install --save socket.io
npm WARN package.json famedu@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json famedu@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json famedu@1.0.0 No README data
|


> ws@0.5.0 install         
c:\codeprojects\famedu\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\en
gine.io\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

/
> ws@0.4.31 install     
c:\codeprojects\famedu\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\s
ocket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


npm ERR! ws@0.5.0 install: `(node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit    
0)`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ws@0.5.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the ws package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ws
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program     
Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "socket.io"
npm ERR! cwd c:\codeprojects\famedu
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have both python 2.x and Visual Studio (Express Edition or higher) installed in order to build native dependencies on Windows.

`ws` is short for web socket; it's a socket client -- see https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws -- and ws needs to be compiled as a binary add-on.

There have been a lot of improvements to npm -- especially around conflicts and race conditions during install -- since 1.4.28. Can you try updating your npm installation?

To update npm on Windows, follow the instructions here: https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows

Comment: Upgrading npm (following the official guide) worked for me. Thanks Sam.